# Nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting error in this line

```
try {
                    if (toolsDialect.getDataStoreType().equals(DataStoreType.SQLSERVER)) {
                        String sqlString = "IF OBJECT_ID('" + t.getName() + "') IS NOT NULL  ";
                        executeSql(jdbc, t.sqlDropString(dialect, null, schema), sqlString);
                    } else {
                        executeSql(jdbc, t.sqlDropString(dialect, null, schema));
                    }
                } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
                    //don't care if table doesn't exist
                }
            }
            if (newTable || modifiedColumns.size() > 0) {
                //create new table with correct structure
                Table t = new Table(createTableName);
                sqlStr.append(dialect.getCreateTableString())
                        .append(" ")
                        .append(t.getQualifiedName(dialect, null, schema)).append("(");
                newColumns.addAll(modifiedColumns);
                for (Iterator it = newColumns.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    ColumnMigrationSpec spec = (ColumnMigrationSpec) it.next();
                    sqlStr.append(spec.columnName);
                    sqlStr.append(" ").append(spec.columnSpec);
                    if (it.hasNext()) sqlStr.append(", ");
                }
                sqlStr.append(")");
                if (tableMeta != null) sqlStr.append(" ").append(tableMeta);
                executeSql(jdbc, sqlStr.toString());
                if (newTable) return 0;
            }

            if (modifiedColumns.size() == 0) {
                Table t = new Table(tableName);
                for (Iterator it = newColumns.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    ColumnMigrationSpec spec = (ColumnMigrationSpec) it.next();
                    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder()
                            .append("alter table ")
                            .append(t.getQualifiedName(dialect, null, schema)).append(" ")
                            .append(dialect.getAddColumnString()).append(" ")
                            .append(spec.columnName).append(" ")
                            .append(spec.columnSpec);
                    executeSql(jdbc, buf.toString());
                }
                for (Iterator it = deletedColumns.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    String colName = (String) it.next();
                    Column col = new Column(colName);
                    String sql = "alter table " + t.getQualifiedName(dialect, null, schema) + " drop column " + col.getQuotedName(dialect);
                    executeSql(jdbc, sql);
                }
                return 0;
            }

            newColumns.removeAll(modifiedColumns);
            modifiedColumns.addAll(newColumns);
            //
            //insert data into new table by selecting from old table
            sqlStr = new StringBuilder(2000);
            Table ct = new Table(createTableName);
            sqlStr.append("insert into ").append(ct.getQualifiedName(dialect, null, schema));
            sqlStr.append("(");
```

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect
>   syntax near ')'. at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)

Can anyone explain why.

Comment: Please show the rest of the `sqlStr` generating code. Also, please print/log the contents of sqlStr at the time the exception was thrown.

Comment: @Jason I have added the sql str. Please have a look.

Comment: As of the current edit of your question, the SQL is: "insert into tablename (" which isn't valid SQL. We need to see what else you add to sqlStr, and what the actual SQL is that is being executed when the exception is thrown.